# Scapy sniff function sniff more than 1 pcap file offline at a time

Tags: python, scapy

At the moment this reads in all the PCAPs files then create a new .dat file based on the PCAP filename, finally it writes in all the TCP/UDP payloads from the pcap file offline

What I need it to do is sniff all the PCAP files not just 1 file at a time

At the moment I have to put the filename of each pcap file here

```py
sniff(offline="(only sniffs 1 PCAP file at a time).pcapng", prn=handler, filter='tcp or udp')
```

How do I get it to sniff all the PCAP files?

```
import glob
import os
from scapy.all import *

def handler(packet):
    for file in glob.glob("*.pcap"):
        f = open((file.rsplit(".", 1) [0] ) +".dat", "wb")
        f.write(str(packet.payload.payload.payload))

sniff(offline="(only sniffs 1 packet at a time).pcapng", prn=handler, filter='tcp or udp')
```

So far I made some progress instead of

```
sniff(offline="(only sniffs 1 PCAP file at a time).pcapng", prn=handler, filter='tcp or udp')
```

I now have

```
sniff(offline=path, prn=handler, filter='tcp or udp')

path = "file1.pcapng, file2.pcapng, file3.pcapng"
```

I now want to know how to iterate through all these pcap files